# Schema.org - Data on hidden elements

Tags: html, seo, schema

How would search engines react if i made a hidden field with schema data in it?

```
$100.00 USD
```

The reason I'm feeling forced to do this is because when I use Google Webmaster Tools to make my schema it requires the price to be tagged.

So do i really need to tag the price, and what would happen if i tagged a hidden price?


*Keep in mind I don't want to show the price in this specific case.*

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to hide the microdata by using the meta tag.

For example,

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <span itemprop="name">Funky Skirt</span>
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="100.00" />
        <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a better way to hide microdata than using css because Google doesn't like it when content is hidden with either

```
visibility: hidden;
```

or

```
display: none;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this tool can help us : 
https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

Comment: This is gold. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing to keep in mind, though, is that if you want Google to display a rich snippet for your product, you must mark up at least the product name, info, offer/price, and the ISO currency code.  So by hiding the price to visitors by using a meta tag, you basically disqualify your product markup for a rich snippet.  You may or may not care about that, but I just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: By info you mean description ?

Comment: Basically, yes.  Of course, you would probably want to include that in your markup anyway.